# Running a localized Test with TestNG

Tags: java, testng, setlocale

I'm stuck here:

My scenario:
I'm running a test with TestNG where I call a function of a 3rd party library. This library gets initialized with Locale.getDefault().

To get the same test result independently from the machine the test is run on, I want to set a specific Locale and reset it afterwards.
Unfortunately, it seems that though I can set the Locale to my desired value, some other tests (not in the same testClass) fail... probably due to formatting issues (localization).

```
private Locale locale;

@BeforeClass
public void init() {
    locale = Locale.getDefault();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
}

@AfterClass
public void teardown() {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "someDataProvider")
public void testThisWithUSLocale(String element) throws Exception {
    String resultToTest = myClass.createSomething(element);

    Assert.assertFalse(resultToTest.isEmpty());
}
```

I tried setting Locale in @BeforeMethod but had the same issue...
Are tests run async? does setting the Locale in this test really affect the other tests?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the locale while the JVM is running is a tricky process, and the whole application needs to be prepared for it. From the javadocs of [`setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault-java.util.Locale-)

> Since changing the default locale may affect many different areas of functionality, this method should only be used if the caller is prepared to reinitialize locale-sensitive code running within the same Java Virtual Machine.

Your test setup looks correct, but whatever your code (or the 3rd party library) do probably doesn't support a change of the Locale.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found the problem:

Locale was initially set for FORMAT. So, by running everything in `@BeforeClass`, my tests worked fine, but after "resetting" everything with `Locale.setDefault(locale);` that I saved earlier (but in a wrong way), I'm setting ALL Categories, and not just FORMAT making the other test fail. Correct is:

```
private Locale locale;

@BeforeClass
public void init() {
        locale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT, Locale.US);
}

@AfterClass
public void teardown() {
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
}
```

Comment: Your `teardown` method still sets the general one, is that intentional?

Comment: yes, im setting the one i saved earlier in init(): ```locale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);```